# Redirecting MySQL request from old to new server

Tags: centos, iptables

I have a Linux webserver (CentOS7) with Tomcat and 2 MS sql server (SqlOLD - 192.168.4.23 and SqlNew - 192.168.4.28).
I need to add a rule (on the webserver) that forwards any packet from OLD to NEW SQL (port tcp/1433).

I need this because there are some webapp compiled with static IP and I can't rebuild them in my own.

Comment: No problem, old server: 192.168.4.23, new server 192.168.4.28. NM: 255.255.240.0. Port is standard 1433 TCP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting problemette. The usual approach for rewriting addresses is to use the NAT `PREROUTING` table, but this won't work here. You can't use `DNAT` in the `PREROUTING` table because traffic isn't coming in to your originating webserver, and `DNAT` isn't permitted in `POSTROUTING`. Instead, this is one of the rare times when `DNAT` should be placed into the `OUTPUT` chain (albeit in the NAT table).

```
iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -o eth0 --dst 192.168.4.23 -j DNAT --to 192.168.4.28
```

This takes all output heading through interface `eth0` (which you may need to adjust for your CentOS environment) that's destined for 192.168.4.23 and rewrites to go to 192.168.4.28. Port numbers *should* remain unchanged. Returning packets should be automatically rewritten provided you've got the conntrack module in your kernel.

To list `iptables` rules you need to run five separate commands (there are five sets of rules), but in practice mostly the first two are sufficient for rules that you would manage.

```
iptables -nvL                # Blocking and permitting packets ("-t filter")
iptables -t nat -nvL         # Rewriting packets, eg different destinations
iptables -t mangle -nvL      # Not used so often
iptables -t raw -nvL         # Used rarely
iptables -t security -nvL    # SELinux
```

To remove a rule you can repeat it, changing `-I` (insert) or `-A` (append) for `-D` (delete).

There are many tutorials about `iptables`. You may find that since you're using CentOS it's worth your while learning about the higher-level firewall tool `firewalld` (see `man firewalld` for a starting point, and of course lots of Google-fu).

Comment: Awesome Roaima it works! Thank you Thank you Thank you! May i ask you how can i show the rule with iptable command? Something like iptables -L -v -n. And how can i remove it without reboot the webserver? Thanks!

Comment: You'll need `iptables -t nat -L -v -n` to show the rule: if you don't specify the `-t` option, the default is equivalent to `-t filter`. Likewise, to remove the rule, you'll need `iptables -t nat -D OUTPUT ...` with either the line number or the rule specification of the rule you wish to remove as the tail end of the command.